# SQL update method returns JSONException

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, sql-update

I have a simple MySQL table on my server with 4 fields. `pid`, `aid`, `uname` and `active`. I am sending the `uname` variable via my android app to my PHP code and I want to change the boolean `active` column from 1 to 0 where the `uname` field is equal to the value I send through the app. This is the code I have: 
The value I send from the android app is received like this in index.php and passed onto the other function in DB_Functions.php

```
else if ($tag == 'notpart'){

    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $notpart = $db->notpart($uname);

    if (!empty($notpart)) {
            // stored successfully
        $response["success"] = 1;
        //$response["notpart"]["aid"] = $notpart["aid"];
        $response["notpart"]["uname"] = $notpart["uname"];

            echo json_encode($response);
        } 
        else {
            // failed to store
            $response["error"] = 1;
            //$response["error_msg"] = "JSON Error occured";
            $response["error_msg"] = mysql_error();
            echo json_encode($response);
        }


}
```

The function in DB_Functions.php:
**UPDATE:** changed `$uname` to `'$uname'`. Now the IllegalStringOffset Warning is gone but JSONException exists

```
public function notpart($uname) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    echo $uname;
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE part SET active='0' WHERE uname = $uname");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
         //get event details 
        $pid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM part WHERE pid = $pid");
         //return event details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return mysql_error();
    }
}
```

But I am getting an Illegal String offset warning and no changes are made to the MySQL table.

Here's the logcat:

```
05-20 21:57:26.958: E/JSON(17919): wwwww<br />n<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'uname' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\shareity\shareity\index.php</b> on line <b>445</b><br />n{"tag":"notpart","success":1,"error":0,"notpart":{"uname":"U"}}n
05-20 21:57:26.958: E/JSON Parser(17919): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value wwwww<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I tried `isset` and `!empty` methods to try to send off the illegal offset error, but nothing worked. Can someone please tell me what's wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE part SET active='0' WHERE uname = $uname");
```

try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE part SET active='0' WHERE `uname` = '$uname'");
```

Also note, you're setting active to `'0'`, not to `0`. Change it to 0 if active field type is INT.

Also, you're asking yourelf for SQLInjection. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Additionally, dont use `mysql` (deprecated) extension. Switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Last thing to fix is to remove `echo $uname;` It breaks json response adding uname to output. This probably breaks your json.

Comment: for boolean use TRUE or FALSE or 1 or 0 if you want o use numeric value  but not '0'

Comment: Okay I changed the field type to INT. And used 0 instead of '0'. Now the String offset warning is gone, after using `'$uname'` instead of `$uname` but now I get a JSON error saying the value of uname (java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject)

Comment: can u attach var_dump of variable you pass to json?

Comment: sorry what is var_dump?

Comment: it's a String. A String that has the value `donor123`

Comment: Updated question, think this is what should get your android error fixed.
Json response must be only json from start till end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78360/discussion-between-yohan-blake-and-gacek).